# Radical Locally Solvable?

Tags: group-theory

A group $G$ is locally solvable if all finitely generated subgroups are
solvable.

A group $G$ is locally finite if all finitely generated subgroups are
finite.

A group $G$ is virtually locally solvable if it has a locally solvable
subgroup of the finite index.

Let be $R(S)=\left\langle T\,;\,T\trianglelefteq G\,,\,T\text{ locally solvable }\right\rangle $

My question are:

1)Is $\,R(S)\,$ locally solvable?

2) If 1) is true: $G$ locally finite, $R(S)$ locally solvable and $G/R(S)$ virtually locally solvable $\Rightarrow G$
virtually locally solvable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your group $R(S)$ need not be locally solvable.  A counterexample due to P. Hall is described in Part 2 of Robinson's "Finiteness Conditions and Generalized Soluble Groups".  See the development leading up to, and the proof of, Theorem 8.19.1 on page 91 (and the corollary).